# Meaning and function of Va'yechulu

Tags: tefilla, words, hebrew

What does Va'yechulu mean literally in Hebrew? What is the function of Va'yechulu during worship?

Answer (score 3):

It's the first word of Genesis 2:1. Genesis 2:1–3 is recited a few times a week in the liturgy, perhaps most notably toward the end of the evening synagogue services on Friday nights: many congregations recite the passage aloud and in unison on that occasion. If you saw a reference to "Va'yechulu", it likely meant that passage and may well have meant that recitation of it.

The word means "(they) were completed": [see the verse for context](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2?lang=he-en). It's the third-person plural [*vav*-consecutive](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waw-consecutive) imperfect (hence past tense) of the [*pu'al* conjugation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_verb_conjugation) of the root "כלה".